# Export HTML Page (Like As CV With Image) As PDF On Client Side

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, model-view-controller, pdf-generation

I have an a page  like as CV. I download it with controller methods in my MVC  web project. Bu i can't download big image. Because  big image has big base 64 string. So html code and base 64 string overflow C# string. So that i can only download small image with controller method. I want to download big image with javascript on client side of the MVC project. How can i download cv html page with profile photo using javascript.